# Why is Hom$_A(M,A)$ a right $\Gamma$ comodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras, stable-homotopy-theory

I'm reading through appendix I (Hopf algebroids) of Ravenel's green book, and I came across a line I can't understand in a proof. The part of the lemma I'm interested in states:

> $\mathbf{Lemma A1.1.6}$
>
> Let $M$ and $N$ be left $\Gamma$-comodules with $M$ projective over $A$ (where ($A$,$\Gamma$) is a Hopf algebroid). Then Hom$_A(M,A)$ is a right $\Gamma$-comodule.

In the proof it's stated that because $M$ is projective, there's a canonical isomorphism 
$$
Hom_A(M,A) \otimes_A N \approx Hom_A(M,N).
$$

If I recall correctly, however, this is only true if $M$ is a finitely generated projective module, in which case you can localize at all primes and reduce it to the case of a finite rank free module.

Is there an implicit finite generation hypothesis on $\Gamma$-comodules that I'm missing, or is there some other way to define the comodule structure?

Comment: Do you mean $Hom_A(M,N)$ in the lemma ?

Comment: There's a natural map $Hom_A(M,N) \rightarrow Hom_A(M,\Gamma \otimes_A N)$.To produce the structure map of the comodule they use the fact in the question with $N = A$ to move the tensor product outside.

Comment: What is Ravenel's green book?

Comment: @darijgrinberg There's an online edition of it here https://www.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/mu.html. I should have added the homotopy theory tag when I first made the question, sorry.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wasn't aware of this book.